# How to add customized hex color code in table layout?

Tags: codenameone

How can I write a code to add  color hex code to table layout row and column which I am actually fetching from my database table based on which I need to change the row and column color of the table layout.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want to convert HEX string to uicolor?

Comment: This is a bit unclear the answer from @tizbn seems closest to what you are asking. If not can you clarify, ideally with a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following codes will help

```
 void test() {
        Form form = new Form(new TableLayout(2, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Label label = new Label(" label " + i);;
            // for header 
            if (i == 0) {
                label.setUIID("HeaderUIID");
                label.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
                label.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
            }
            form.addComponent(label);
        }
    }
```